# Creation and annhilation operator in the Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I am trying to calculate the time evolution of the creation/anni. operator in the Heisenber picture.

On this webpage http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node191.html, they used the Heisenber equation of motion, but instead of using the operators in the Heisenberg picture, they used the operators in the Schrödinger picture.

Why does this work?

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because (assuming a time independent Hamiltonian, operators without subscript referring to Schrödinger operators, those with the subscript $H$ to Heisenberg operators):
\begin{align*}
[a_H(t), H_H(t)] &= e^{-iHt/\hbar} a e^{iHt/\hbar} e^{-iHt/\hbar} H e^{iHt/\hbar} - e^{-iHt/\hbar} H e^{iHt/\hbar} e^{-iHt/\hbar} a e^{iHt/\hbar} \\
                 &= e^{-iHt/\hbar} (aH - Ha) e^{iHt/\hbar} = e^{-iHt/\hbar} [a, H] e^{iHt/\hbar} \\
                 &= e^{-iHt/\hbar} \hbar \omega a e^{iHt/\hbar} = \hbar \omega e^{-iHt/\hbar} a e^{iHt/\hbar} = \hbar \omega a_H(t).
\end{align*}

Note that $e^{A}e^{-A} = 1$.

When looking carefully at the proof, one can see, that this calculation can easily be generalized to prove that $[A_H, B_H] = [A, B]_H$ (we only used the concrete properties of $H$ and $a$ in the last steps).