# Can we infer time evolution of an operator from a given time evolution of functions (sums or products) of that operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, unitarity

Let's assume that I describe my theory using an operator $\Phi(\vec{x}, t)$, and that I know the time evolution for functions of this operator. (For example, the time-evolution for $\Phi^\dagger(\vec{x}, t)\Phi(\vec{x}, t)$ is given as a unitary map $U$.)

Can we now in general infer that $U$ must describe $\Phi$’s time evolution as well? Or could there be some freedom in $\Phi$’s time evolution that will cancel out looking at the time evolution of functions of $\Phi$? Taking the product of $\Phi$ and its hermitean conjugate here is just an example.

The reason why I'm asking is that for observables, there are many (for me) very intuitive arguments on why observables time evolution should be given a unitary map $e^{i\hat{H}t}$. However, these intuitive arguments break down when I look at QFT, where field operators aren't in general hermitean anymore, and I'd like to "save" them somehow.

EDIT:

As an Example, if we know that
\begin{align}
\Phi^{\dagger} \Phi |_{t} = U^{-1} \Phi^{\dagger} \Phi |_{t=0} U
\end{align}
Then of course
\begin{align}
\Phi |_{t} = U^{-1}  \Phi |_{t=0} U
\end{align}
Would be a choice for the time evolution of $\Phi(t)$ that is consistent with the requirement. But is it the only possible one?

I know that we usually assume time-evolution to be a feature of the field operators, but I explicitly want to talk about abitrary operators.

Comment: What do you mean by describing a theory using an operator? Is it a field operator in terms of which your theory is formulated?

Comment: @flippiefanus Yes, this es exactly the the case I thought about. Equations of "motion" are formulated for  the field operator, but observables are usually only products of field operators (I'm still on my way to find out why exactly that is the case)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean, but if $\Phi$ is an arbitrary operator, then $\Phi^\dagger\Phi$ certainly won't contain the full information about $\Phi$ in *all* cases. E.g. for a unitary $\Phi$, the product $\Phi^\dagger\Phi=1$ contains no information at all.

Comment: @noah $\Phi$ is not meant to be unitary, but $U$ is. Or maybe I'm missunderstanding you?

Comment: But if you say $\Phi$ can be *any* operator, it certainly could be unitary as well, right? Otherwise it should be more specific. Just trying to figure out what exactly you mean in the question.

Comment: Heisenberg's equations of motion don't assume the operator is Hermitian. There is only one unitary time evolution operator (modulo an overall phase).

Comment: @Andrew what do you mean by "there is only one unitary time evolution operator"?

There are serveral "derivations" of unitary time evolution (see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0101012 ), but they all only make statements about observables, (which need to be represented by hermitean operators).

Comment: @noah I see what you mean. I guess  I need to narrow down what $\Phi$ is supposed to be, or I need to be more specific in what functions of $\Phi$ I'm willing to allow.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp In the Heisenberg picture, time evolution of operators is determined by the Heisenberg equation of motion. This equation does not assume that the operators being evolved are Hermitian. For example, you can derive evolution equations obeyed by the creation and annihilation operators, here is a PSE question/answer covering this point: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188785/creation-and-annhilation-operator-in-the-heisenberg-picture

Comment: @Andrew the whole question I ask comes from a point of view where I don't yet know wether all time evolution is given by the Heisenberg equations of motion. I'm asking wether - if I know that the Heisenberg equations of motion do hold for a certain observable (operator), wether there is no other option than it holding as well for all operators that this observable is a function of.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp It sounds like your question is "given some starting assumption about time evolution on some set of operators, what are all the possible set of logically consistent extensions of time evolution to a larger set of operators." In that case I think you need to specify your question more precisely: what exactly is the starting set, ending set, and requirements you have for an extension. Having said that if you want the final result of this process to be quantum mechanics, all operators (not just Hermitian ones) have to obey the Heisenberg equations of motion.